# How to set column-order in wmic output?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, wmic

I use wmic mostly as a linux-ps-equivalent in this way:

`wmic process where (name="java.exe") get processId, commandline`

But the output columns are ordered alphabetically so I get:

```
CommandLine                            ProcessId
java -cp ... some.Prog arg1 arg2 ...   2345
java -cp ... other.Prog arg1 arg2 ...  3456
```

When what I want is:

```
ProcessId  CommandLine
2345       java -cp .... some.Prog arg1 arg2 ...
3456       java -cp .... other.Prog arg1 arg2 ...
```

Which would be much more readable when the commandline is long.

I'm thinking of writing a ps.bat to simplify the syntax for my use, so any batch script solutions for post-processing the wmic output are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple batch file would do the job (only for your case).

It determines the start position of the second column by searching for `ProcessId`, and then each line will be reordered

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "first=1"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"wmic process where (name="cmd.exe") get processId, commandline"`) DO (
    set "line=%%a"
    if defined first (
        call :ProcessHeader %%a
        set "first="
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    ) ELSE (
        call :ProcessLine
    )
)
exit /b

:ProcessHeader line
set "line=%*"
set "line=!line:ProcessID=#!"
call :strlen col0Length line
set /a col1Start=col0Length-1
exit /b

:ProcessLine
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!line:~0,-1!"
if defined line (
    set "col0=!line:~0,%col1Start%!"
    set "col1=!line:~%col1Start%!"
    echo(!col1!!col0!
)
Endlocal
exit /b

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: this looks good although a bit complex, and even though I've had problems with getting the delayed expansion to work properly in the past, I will give this a chance as soon as time permits ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is directly accessing the **Win32_Process SQL table** of the WMI via VBS, without using WMIC. Then you can manage exactly which columns, column ordering and their output format.

**Here's the VBS code for CSV output:** `processList.vbs`

```
' === Direct access to Win32_Process data ===
' -------------------------------------------
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set service = locator.ConnectServer()
Set processes = service.ExecQuery ("select ProcessId,CommandLine,KernelModeTime,UserModeTime from Win32_Process")

For Each process in processes
   Return = process.GetOwner(strNameOfUser) 
   wscript.echo process.ProcessId & "," & process.KernelModeTime & "," & process.UserModeTime & "," & strNameOfUser & "," & process.CommandLine
Next

Set WSHShell = Nothing
```

**Command line usage:** `cscript //NoLogo processList.vbs`

Win32_Process column list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx

Original Java code here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html

Comment: seems very powerful. I like it. I will definetly try this out. Thank you :D